# Convert HTML to markdown

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, markdown

I have an app and the admin can create article , and i use the markitup markdown editor for add title etc. Now in my view i want convert this markdown text in html.

So in my view if for exemple when admin write the article he write **exemple** , in the view the text are in bold.

I hope you understand and you can help me.

I  install redcarpet and i put in my application helper this  :

```
module ApplicationHelper


 def markdown(text)
if text
  markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(
    Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new
  )
  markdown.render(text).html_safe
end
```

end

and in my show view this :

```
 <%= markdown(@article.content) %>
```

I restarted my server but i have one error :

uninitialized constant ApplicationHelper::Redcarpet
EDIT 2 :

THANK's All works !!! !!!!!

Comment: add `require 'redcarpet'` before `module ApplicationHelper`

Comment: when i add require 'redcarpet' i have this error now  Missing helper file helpers/redcarpet.rb

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems you need this gem

- [reverse_markdown](https://github.com/xijo/reverse_markdown)

> Transform existing html into markdown in a simple way, for example if you want to import existings tags into your markdown based application.

- [html2markdown](https://github.com/29decibel/html2markdown)

> Simple html to Markdown ruby gem
> We love markdown, cause it is friendly to edit. So we want everything to be markdown

- [upmark](https://github.com/conversation/upmark)

> A HTML to Markdown converter.
>
> Upmark defines a parsing expression grammar (PEG) using the very awesome Parslet gem. This PEG is then used to convert HTML into Markdown in 4 steps:
>
> 1. Parse the XHTML into an abstract syntax tree (AST).
> 2. Normalize the AST into a nested hash of HTML elements.
> 3. Mark the block and span-level subtrees which should be ignored (table, div, span, etc).
> 4. Convert the AST leaves into Markdown.

---

> uninitialized constant ApplicationHelper::Redcarpet

Add `require 'redcarpet'` before `module ApplicationHelper`

```
require 'redcarpet'
module ApplicationHelper


  def markdown(text)
    Redcarpet.new(text).html_safe
  end
end
```

Answer (score 16):

The [kramdown](https://rubygems.org/gems/kramdown) gem provides an HTML to Markdown solution in pure Ruby.

```
irb> html = 'How to convert <b>HTML</b> to <i>Markdown</i> on <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>.'
=> "How to convert <b>HTML</b> to <i>Markdown</i> on <a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com\">Stack Overflow</a>."
irb> document = Kramdown::Document.new(html, :html_to_native => true)
=> <KD:Document: ... >
irb> document.to_kramdown
=> "How to convert **HTML** to *Markdown* on [Stack Overflow][1].\n\n\n\n[1]: http://stackoverflow.com\n"
```

Comment: Kramdown is the best Markdown parser out there (as in: powers all of Jekyll). Upvoted.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [redcarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet) gem to compile markdown into html in rails.

---

With redcarpet you can than do the following:

```
# application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper

  def markdown(text)
    if text
      markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(
        Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new
      )
      markdown.render(text).html_safe
    end
  end
end

# some_view.html.erb
<%= markdown(@article.body) %>
```

Comment: I use redcarpet and i have an error  uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Redcarpet but i follow the railscasts.

Comment: have you restarted your rails server?

Comment: Okay, I added an example markdown helper method which would render your markdown to html. Hope that helps.

Comment: I have the same error :uninitialized constant ApplicationHelper::Redcarpet

Comment: Have you run `bundle install` after adding `gem 'redcarpet'` to your Gemfile? If I remove it from my Gemfile I get the same error.

Comment: The question was HTML to markdown not markdown to HTML